# Is there a multivariate analogue of the Discrete Inverse Transform Sampling?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sampling, monte-carlo, computational-statistics

**Context :** I have been tasked for an assignment with the implementation of a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm to simulate the [Ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model). In short, this model consists - in the case I'm considering - in a two-dimensional lattice (i.e. $\mathcal{T} = (\mathbb{Z}/L\mathbb{Z})^2$ where $L$ is an integer and represents the size of the square) where at each point $x \in \mathcal{T}$, there is a spin $\sigma(x) \in \{-1,1\}$.

The system as defined will then follow [Gibbs distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_measure) :
$$\pi(\sigma) := \frac{1}{Z} e^{-H(\sigma)/T},\quad \forall \sigma\in\{-1,1\}^{\mathcal{T}} $$

Where $Z$ is a normalization constant, $T$ is a constant called the temperature and $H(\cdot)$ is the hamiltonian of the system which is not relevant to my question.

**My problem :** Using the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm to sample a configuration $\sigma$ from Gibbs distribution works fine, and I wanted to benchmark it against other common sampling methods such as [Rejection Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) and [Inverse Transform Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).
Rejection Sampling is fine, but I don't see how to perform Inverse Transform Sampling for a multivariate **discrete** distribution such as this one. I've only seen it in the univariate case and haven't been able to find anything online for the multivariate case. As a reminder, here is how it works for a univariate distribution :

> **Discrete Inverse Transform Sampling (Univariate) :** For a non-negative random variable $X$ with probability mass function $p(k) = \mathbb{P}(X = k) \,\, \forall k\ge 0$, one can sample one realisation of $X$ by applying these steps :
>
> 1. Generate $U \sim \text{uniform}(0,1)$
> 2. If $U \le p(0)$, return $k=0$
> 3. Else, return the only $k\ge 1$ such that $$ \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} p(i) < U \le \sum_{i=0}^{k} p(i) $$

(The proof that this procedure is correct can be found, e.g., in [these notes](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eks20/4404-Sigman/4404-Notes-ITM.pdf).)
Intuitively, I feel like there is no way to adapt this to the multivariate case, since it relies on the ordering of the integers to compute the CDF, which is not possible in dimensions $\ge 1$.

A way of dealing with the problem could be to index all the possible configurations $ (\sigma_i)_{i \in (1,\ldots,2^{L^2})} $ and to use the univariate procedure on this ordering, but this is extremely unsatisfactory since the ordering is arbitrary and this gives no guarantee that I'm sampling according to $\pi$.

**Question :** Is there a Multivariate analogue of **Discrete** Inverse Transform Sampling ? Or can the indexing of the $(\sigma_i)$ be done in a way that yields the desired results ? If so, I would also appreciate resources with proofs and/or examples.

Comment: Hi: Your question sounds interesting but I'm pressed for time and I'd have to really sit down and study what you said carefully to have any hope of even just understanding the issue much less solving it.  Radford Neal is probably someone who could answer your question but I don't know if you want to ask him. Still, I did google and found below which hopefully can provide some insight ?   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1689946/multivariate-inverse-transformation-sampling

Comment: Here's one more. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50908047/sampling-from-multivariate-customised-cumulative-distribution-function-in-matlab

Comment: The Ising distribution cannot be simulated exactly unless $L$ is very small. The closest approach is to use perfect sampling à la Propp & Wilson (see the recent book by [Huber](https://amzn.to/2ZekbPL)).

Comment: Thank you for the links @mlofton, I had already seen them but unfortunately I have a hard time seeing how I would transcribe that for a discrete distribution... I will think again and get back at you.

Thank you as well Xi'an for letting me know about perfect sampling, it sounds great, I'll give it a look ! However I'm still wondering if, generally speaking, it is possible to generalize Discrete inverse transform sampling to the multivariate case. I'll edit my post when I have some time to provide some more details.

Comment: @StratosFair: Yes, if you can  let me know if you find anything. It's appreciated.